# Seam3 @ViewConfig redirect page https

Tags: java, jsf, jboss7.x, seam

I have seam 3.1.0 Final application, use @ViewConfig for security part, it works fine redirect http,

```
@ViewConfig
public interface AppViewConfig {

static enum Checkout {
    @ViewPattern("/test/*")
    @User
    ADMIN,

    @FacesRedirect
    @ViewPattern("/*")
    @AccessDeniedView("/denied.xhtml")
    @LoginView("/login.xhtml") //todo I need redirect https://localhost:443/myApp/login.xhtml
    ALL;
}
```

}

but I need to redirect to a https for example ("https://domain.com:443/myApp/login.xhtml") page
how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Seam 3 handles JSF with a subsystem named Seam Faces. And according to this [Seam Faces issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SEAMFACES-192) the problem of specifying a http or https scheme for a page is still not solved.